# I cannot upgrade

Tags: composer, 9, upgrading

I'm currently with Drupal 8.9.13 and trying to update to Drupal 9. When I try the below command it says Nothing to install or update.
`composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies`

When I try the command `composer require drupal/core-recommended:^9.1.4` I get the following message.

```
  `Problem 1
- Can only install one of: typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v3.1.6, v3.1.4].
- Can only install one of: typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v3.1.6, v3.1.4].
- Can only install one of: typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v3.1.6, v3.1.4].
- drupal/core-recommended 9.1.4 requires typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v3.1.6 -> satisfiable by typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v3.1.6].
- Installation request for drupal/core-recommended 9.1.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[9.1.4].
- Installation request for typo3/phar-stream-wrapper (locked at v3.1.4) -> satisfiable by typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v3.1.4].`
```

Please help me to get this solved as I'm not sure what to check next.

Thanks

Hi, I have used `composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-dependencies` and received the below.

```
Dependency "typo3/phar-stream-wrapper" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "typo3/phar-stream-wrapper" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating drupal/core-composer-scaffold (8.9.7 => 8.9.13): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/core-project-message (8.9.7 => 8.9.13): Loading from cache
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

I have also tried using `composer require typo3/phar-stream-wrapper ^3.1.6` and the result was:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.13 requires typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v3.1.4 -> satisfiable by typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v3.1.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.13 requires typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v3.1.4 -> satisfiable by typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v3.1.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.13 requires typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v3.1.4 -> satisfiable by typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v3.1.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for drupal/core-recommended (locked at 8.9.13, required as ^8.8) -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[8.9.13].
```

Please find my composer.json below.

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "2.4",
        "drupal/authorization": "1.0-beta5",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
        "drupal/ldap": "4.0-alpha3",
        "drupal/ldap_sso": "4.0-alpha1",
        "drupal/ultimate_cron": "2.0-alpha5",
        "drupal/webform": "5.17",
        "drupal/webform_views": "5.0-alpha7",
        "typo3/phar-stream-wrapper": "3.1.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drush/drush": "^10.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: When it's a Composer question, please include your composer.json. Can it be that there are other packages with drupal/core-* in their name? Also try `composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-dependencies` and tell us in an edit to your post what happened. Many thanks

Comment: You may need to include more packages to update on the command line.  I suspect it might need the drupal/core:^9.1.4.  Or you may just need to specify the typo/phar-stream-wrapper version.  Composer's often will not update a package it is not sure of but will if you tell it to.

Comment: @CGMonroe I have tried using 'composer update typo/phar-stream-wrapper' and the result was 'Package "typo/phar-stream-wrapper" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.'

Comment: I'd just manually change `^8.8` to `^9.0` on the core packages and then run the update command from my first comment again.